# Getting Taxonomy term name from target ID - D9

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-9

Getting Taxonomy term name from Taxonomy target ID:

I have a taxonomy term that accepts multiple values. It's rendered as a multiselectfield. I am trying to read the target ID of the field and figure the term name out of it using the below code in a preprocess function:

```
 $granttype = $user_entity->field_user_grant_type->getValue();
  foreach($granttype as $gt)
  {
    $granttype_name = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($gt)->label();
  }
  dd($granttype_name);
  
  $variables['grant_type'] = $granttype_name;
```

dd($granttype) shows the below output:

[image]

However, the foreach loop to figure out the term name is not working correctly.

dd($granttype_name) results as:

```
 The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Illegal offset type in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load() (line 297 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
```

I am looping through the target ID and trying to get the term name. But it's not working. Any help pls?

---

UPDATE: I tried the below line of code:

```
 $term = term::load($gt);
    $name = $term->getName();
```

still no luck :( same error

Comment: in your code, I think $gt is an array, try using `$gt['target_id']`

Comment: you printed the wrong variable: `dd($granttype_name)` instead of `dd($granttype)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example how to do this:

```
  $grant_type = $user_entity->field_user_grant_type->entity;
  if ($grant_type instanceof \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface) {
    var_dump($grant_type->label());
  }
```

If you have multiple referenced terms, use:

```
  $grant_types = $user_entity->field_user_grant_types->referencedEntities();
  foreach ($grant_types as $grant_type) {
    var_dump($grant_type->label());
  }
```

Explanation:

1. The generic way to get entity title is the [Entity::label](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Alabel/8.2.x) method
   `$term->label()`;
2. There is a helpful method [Entity::referencedEntities](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.2.x) to get relations.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface;
```

Second, retrieve the value(s) stored in your field (field_user_grant_type) and store them in an array:

```
$myArray = array();
$granttype = $user_entity->get('field_user_grant_type')->getValue();
```

`$granttype` will now contain an array of arrays. Next, you need to gather the actual term IDs

```
foreach($granttype as $type){
   $myArray[] = $type['target_id'];
}
```

Finally, loop through $myArray and fetch the term IDs stored there, and then use each ID to get its corresponding Term Name. Here, I store them in a new array called `grantTypeNames`

```
grantTypeNames = array();
foreach($myArray as $term_id){
   $grantTypeNames[] = Term::load($term_id)->get('name')->value;
}
```

The array `$grantTypeNames` will now contain the term names you want. I hope that helps.